# Fano geometry - order

Tags: geometry, finite-geometry

Of any three points situated on a line, there is no more than one which lies between the other two.

I suspect this is not true in Fano geometry, but I am not entirely sure (the confustion stems from the fact that I am not sure if I have the right interpretation of this axiom) Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fano geometry is constructed of seven lines and seven points.  Two points determine a unique line, and any two lines intersect at a unique point, since it is a projective plane.

Since there are only 3 points on a given line in the Fano geometry (if you don't know what it looks like, it's the Deathly Hallows with two extra elder wands), there can be at most 1 point between any two.

Comment: Love the Deathly Hallows reference. +1

Comment: So the axiom is true for the Fano geometry?

Comment: Yes axoims hold true, here is a reference regarding axioms and Fano's geometry: web.mnstate.edu/jamesju/Spr2011/Content/M487-1_2Fano.pdf‎